# Field injection works but constructor injection returns NullPointerException

Tags: spring

While looking at an existing Spring application, I stumbled upon a class with field injection, which we all know isn't recommended for various reasons. I have then decided to refactor it to make use of a more appropriate approach: constructor based DI.

**Before refactoring**

```
@Component
public class MaintenanceModeInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static final String MAINTENANCE_MODE_VIEW = "common/maintenanceMode";

    @Autowired  
    private ApplicationObject applicationObject;

    public MaintenanceModeInterceptor() {
        // Required by Spring
    }
...
}
```

**After refactoring**

```
@Component
public class MaintenanceModeInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static final String MAINTENANCE_MODE_VIEW = "common/maintenanceMode";

    private ApplicationObject applicationObject;

    public MaintenanceModeInterceptor() {
        // Required by Spring
    }

    @Autowired  
    public MaintenanceModeInterceptor(ApplicationObject applicationObject) {
        this.applicationObject = applicationObject;
    }
...
}
```

Maybe it is related to the fact that a default constructor is present. However, if I remove it, I end up having this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: my.application.web.interceptor.MaintenanceModeInterceptor: method <init>()V not found
```

So my understanding is that Spring requires a default constructor for interceptors.

Is there any way to achieve construtor based DI in this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should remove the non @Autowired constructor and do perform a clean build on your project.

Comment: Worked. And in MvcConfig.java, I have autowired ApplicationObject applicationObject as a field, and then used it to define the MaintenanceModeInterceptor @Bean. I suggest that you post an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the non `@Autowired` constructor and do perform a clean build on your project.